# How to remove border in wx.Notebook

Tags: python, wxpython

How can I remove the border, that looks horrible in my program, from a wx.Notebook? I tried the style flag wx.NO_BORDER, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Citing Robin Dunn from [here](http://wxpython-users.1045709.n5.nabble.com/No-border-for-wx-Notebook-tp2358191p2358192.html)

> The border styles are a suggestion, not a commandment.  It is up to each 
>   widget and/or platform to decide what to do with them.